# trying to implement a function that turns a nested list of a phonebook to a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that receives a nested list of a phonebook, and turn it to a python dictionary so that I can search by name.

For example :

```
phonebook = [["Office", '461888', '61555', '612444'],["Home",'1', '743369'],["School",'7891525', '4771366'], ["Friend1",'556', '4102'],["Friend2",'4007']]

def python_dictionary(phn=phonebook):
```

How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def python_dictionary(phn):
    res = dict()
    for item in phn:
        res[item[0]] = item[1:]
    return res
```

Comment: thanks ! and how can i do a search by phone number ?

Comment: res = python_dictionary(phonebook)
number = res["name"]

Comment: i meant that i need define a function that gets a phone number as an input and outputs the name of the person.

Comment: trying to work on it but dont quite understand all the syntax.

Comment: Please refer to Python's documentation. StackOverflow is for concrete questions about specific problems, not explaining the basics of a language syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can take each element of the phonebook, turn it in to an dictionary like that :

```
def python_dictionary(phn=phonebook):
   #Create the phonebook array
   phn_arr=[]
   for contact in phn:
      #create every contact dictionary
      contact_dic={}
      #add the name
      contact_dic["name"]=contact[0]
      #add the nums using for_loop
      for i in range(2, len(contact)):
         contact_dic["num"+str(i-1)]=contact[i]
      #add the contact to the phn_dic
      phn_arr.append(contact_dic)
   #finaly return phn_arr
   return phn_arr
```

NB:

- This code will return an array of contact dictionary
- If in the given phonebook, contact don't start with the name, it will be problematic, cause this code consider the the first element every contact(in format list) have the name at index 0.